# Given eigenvectors of a graph, how different eigenvalues shape the graph?

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose I give you a graph representation matrix $X= U \Lambda U^\top$, where $X$ can be the (normalized) adjacency or Laplacian matrix with weights in $\mathbb{R}$, $U$ its eigenvectors and $\Lambda$ its eigenvalues.

For fixed $U$, what is the effect of changing $\Lambda$ on the **structure** of the graph? For instance, can new edges appear or disappear?

Comment: Take two points. You have only two possible graphs on two points. Both graphs have the same eigenvectors, but different eigenvalues

Comment: But in your example the two graphs are the isolated-nodes graph and the complete graph. Isn't it a very specific case not generalizable to graphs with more nodes?

Comment: it's just an example that shows how changing the eigenvalues can affect the whole structure

Comment: Some classic spectral properties of the graphs are the number of connected components tied to the kernel of the laplacian, and the spectral gap (smallest non-zero eigenvalue of the laplacian) tied to the connectiveness

Comment: I am aware of the Laplacian spectral properties such as the second eigenvalue related to the connectiveness. Assume that apart from the first eigenvalue, all the others are different from zero. Does the structure remain the same apart from edge-rescaling?

Comment: YES. Suppose that a graph and its complement are both connected. Then they have the same Laplacian eigenvectors

Comment: Ok, this requires that the matrix $X$ is a Laplacian then. What if $X$ is an adjacency matrix? Would that hold again? And as a side question, are you aware of other matrix representations of a graph that are not adjacency/Laplacian and their normalized versions?

Comment: even with the adjacency matrix you have a similar problem. If a graph is d-regular, then its complement has the same adjacency eigenvectors

Comment: But again, this is a very specific case. Can you say it holds for non regular graphs?

Comment: If you want the most general thing, then if you fix the eigenvectors of the adjacency matrix and choose randomly the eigenvalues, you will end up almost certainly with a complete weighted graph